# How to obtain TimezoneType instance in response to here geocoding calls

Tags: here-api

Similar questions have been asked before, but the response has always been to use the TimeZoneOffset from the AdminInfo element. However, this is just an offset and is not sufficient if you want to know the actual time zone.

The TimezoneType element is documented here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html#resource-type-response-geocode__timezone

The geocoding API documentation (https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-geocode.html) documents the locationattributes parameter and timeZone option, but this appears to have no effect.

So the question is, is it possible, using any Here API resource, to obtain a complete TimezoneType instance, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get TimezoneType data with all fields. Instead of using gen=8 in your query, you have to use gen=9. Below is an example query for which timeZone details are provided in the response. Hope this helps!

Sample Request:

```
http://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?gen=9&jsonattributes=1&language=en-US&locationattributes=timeZone&mapview=-23.4842168%2C-46.5935476%3B-23.4967132%2C-46.573592&maxresults=20&searchtext=2215%20e%202&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx
```

Sample Response:

```
    adminInfo": {
        "timeZone": {
            "offset": -7200,
            "rawOffset": -10800,
            "nameShort": "BRT",
            "nameLong": "Brasilia Time",
            "nameDstShort": "BRST",
            "nameDstLong": "Brasilia Summer Time",
            "inDaylightTime": true,
            "dstSavings": 3600,
            "id": "America/Sao_Paulo"
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, confirmed that after adding gen: 9 parameter AdminInfo.TimeZone contains detailed time zone information. I hadn't noticed that parameter - thanks very much for the information!